# Google Cloud vs Amazon S3: Best option for cloud storage in a implementation

Tags: amazon-s3, google-cloud-storage

We need to implement a solution in Salesforce Lightning based on a service to uploading large videos or pictures. But the traffic will not be significant. On the other hand, the service will be accessible from to multiple external sites. 
In terms of cost and performance, what would you recommend me?